# bootstrap get crazy date format when editing a date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, date, bootstrap-datepicker

So, I have a rails application which there is a datepicker. When I put the date for the first time in the calendar it appears in this format: `dd-mm-yyyy`.

But rails save in the database in this format: `yyyy-mm-dd`.
When I go to edit this in the form, the datepicker get crazy, it appears a 1900 year, not the actual year.

I know this happens because the format date is different(the date which bootstrap expects and the date which is saved).

I tried change the datepicker format in the edit view(.html.erb) but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

```
<%= f.text_field :my_date, "data-provide" => 'datepicker',
'data-date-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy', class: 'datepicker form-control', :required => true %>
```

Comment: Can you change the picker format to the one you use on your database? like: `'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'`?

Comment: @William-H-M I already tried this and it isn't worked :(

Comment: how about using [`date_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)  instead of `text_field`

Comment: Could this be related/help? [Issues #18](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails/issues/18)

Comment: @William-H-M I tried this now, and it isn't worked :(

Comment: @sircapsalot is there a difference between data_select and text_field?